# How to remove zoom from product details page on 1.9 RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd, rwd-theme, product-view

How do you remove the zoom feature from Magento 1.9's rwd theme?

I can remove it with css

```
div.zoomContainer {
  display: none;
}
```

But I don't think this is the best method?  It would be better to remove it from a template file or with xml.

I've tried editing the template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml but had no luck.

Comment: No, it isn't the right method, for now see last answer with my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, the zoom feature starts in the `createZoom` function of the `ProductMediaManager` in `/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js` file.

So, another option is to override the individual `createZoom` function via JS later in the process.

For example, if you are inserting JS as a part of your own theme, then you can add the following to override the `createZoom` function in the `ProductMediaManager` object.

```
// ProductMediaManager is outside document.read scope
if (typeof ProductMediaManager !== 'undefined') {

  // Override image zoom in /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js
  // and prevent the zooming of images on hover
  ProductMediaManager.createZoom = function(image) { return; }

}
```

With this method, you don't have to copy the entire `app.js` file. However, you must make sure that your theme's JS is added after the parent theme's JS file. I find this to be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Worked for me, but keep in mind that the overwrite can't be loaded too late. I had wrapped it in a jQuery document ready observer, and it was too late for the overwrite to do anything. Instead I had to execute the overwrite right as my custom JS file was loaded, so I just placed it outside of the jQuery document ready observer.

Answer (score 15):

Create an override of file /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js
(for example in /skin/frontend/rwd/mystyle/js/app.js)

comment the line `(default line: 649)`:

```
//image.elevateZoom();
```

Refresh the Magento cache.

Comment: I have edited because is the right method.

Comment: Slightly better solution may be to just add a `return;` statement at the very beginning of this `createZoom` function which this `image.elevateZoom();` call resides in. That way none of the client side JavaScript even has to execute in the first place. (still follow the practice of overriding this file in your local theme first)

Answer (score -3):

Open `/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`,
In `<catalog_product_view>` section comment below line

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script></action>
```

Comment: thanks, but if remove that js file I can no longer select the thumbnail images for the main gallery area

Comment: It isn't a right method to disable this function.

Comment: You should never be modifying the files in **/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/** OR any of the files in **/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/**. Doing so does not follow upgrade friendly practices. Layout updates should always be done in "local.xml" within your theme. There isn't any layout XML instructions, that cannot be overridden, modified, removed, etc., in local.xml.

Comment: This would throw an error because it wouldn't be able to find elevatezoom