# Stop Zoom on small images on Magento 1.9.0.1 RWD theme

Tags: rwd, ce-1.9.0.1, zoom

I cant seem to stop the new rwd zoom from trying to zoom even on small images works fine for images that are bigger than the product image dispaly area box but with a small image the zoom still activates and displays the identical sized image as the zoom which looks a mess.

In the old Magento versions i think the zoom never activated if the image was smaller than the image holder, but i cant find how to stop it in 1.9.0.1 rwd.

Any ideas would be great, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference if anyone else comes across to this question via google since it was the first google result when I searched for this problem what I did was change in file

skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\app.js

around line 614

```
IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD: 400,
```

to fix the behaviour so it won't look bad. So the script will work now only for much larger pictures. Other than that you can probably disable it completely by removing the code around line 649

```
image.elevateZoom();
```

as it was suggested in [another person's question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/how-to-remove-zoom-from-product-details-page-on-1-9-rwd-theme) so it won't activate the function. Or you can increase the threshold to a very large number if that doesn't work for u.