# Error after removing jQuery elevate

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, local.xml, elevate

I removed the jQuery elevate script from my site using this in the `local.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Only problem, is that there is an error in the console that says it misses this file:

```
app.js:649 Uncaught TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function
```

Is there any clean way to remove this error, while also removing the script?

UPDATE

I noticed, by removing the script, the image switching does not work anymore (switching between images to display them in the bigger image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you want to disable the zoom so you will have to override the `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js` in your custom theme and remove/comment the following line:

```
image.elevateZoom();
```

It's line 1194 in Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: So I have to copy the whole app.js file and remove one line? Not that it would not work, but is there a nicer way?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen unfortunately no. As this line is calling a method from the Elevate class it will always trigger an error if you remove the library so you'll have to delete / comment it. You can do it directly in the rwd/default theme if you don't want to copy the file in your theme but you'll loose this change if you upgrade Magento

Comment: okay, well, thanks anyway. Any chance you might know why the 'image switching' functionality doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen well that's a different topic. Could be anything from JS error to template issue. Feel free to ask a different question explaining what the problem is exactly, what you tried already.

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen here's an answer that'll help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84643/2380

Comment: Small comment, in my app.js file (also magento 1.9.2.4), it is line number 649